# Hibernate lazy loading modifying values

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm working on extending a REST API written in Java using the Spring framework, Hibernate ORM and Jackson for JSON (de)serialization.

On a few API calls, I need to return a user's account given a provided value (say, a subscription ID). There are different types of accounts, so a type value is included so the client can determine what kind of account they're dealing with.

In my controller, I pass the provided user ID down to the service call which calls this method:

```
public Account getAccountBySubscriptionId(long subscriptionId) {
    ServiceSubscription subscription = subscriptionDAO.load(subscriptionId);
    if(subscription != null) {
        return subscription.getAccount();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I would expect this to return JSON similar to this:

```
{
    "type":"account_type_goes_here",
    "id":1,
    "accountNumber":"100"
}
```

However, it appears that Hibernate's lazy loading is modifying the type value, as such (note that UserAccount is the class of the object):

```
{
     "type":"UserAccount_$$_javassist_1",
     "id":2,
     "accountNumber":"37"
}
```

How could I make Hibernate retain the original value for type instead of modifying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure there isn't an error in your logic that's returning the type of the object and not the string value of the type of the account?

Comment: I don't think so - similar code is used elsewhere which returns the account type as expected. I'll double check that though.

Comment: You were right - there was some weird logic in the model causing this. Thanks!